# How do I remove decimals from cent amounts?

Tags: education

How do I change "23.96" CENTS into something that makes sense? Can I just say \$ $0.2396$? It's important that I keep the value behind the decimal I just don't know how.

Comment: mostly you round to the nearest integer. Thus $23.96\approx 24$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer

Comment: I cannot do that, I'm calculating a bill and it needs to be exact.

I'm comparing between two companies and one charges "0.2298" cents per kWh of electricity and this one charges "23.96" cents. I need them to both be like the first number for my spreadsheet. Please help.

Comment: @JadeElizabeth, if one company is charging 23.96 cents, I doubt the other is charging 0.2298 cents.  The latter number should either be written as *22.98* cents or 0.2298 *dollars*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can say $\$0.2396$  People quote prices in fractional cents all the time.  Usually they are things you buy in quantity.  The only problem comes when you have to make change, but then you just round the value.

Comment: So 0.2396 is correct? I was worried it might be wrong and I really need to be as exact as possible :).

Comment: Yes, 0.2396 is correct.  There is no limit on decimals of a dollar.  You are only held to two places when you actually handle coins or pay the final bill because the penny is the smallest unit available.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm getting really stressed out about my electricity bill. No matter what I do I cannot get to the same amounts they are, even if I do round up... I'm $6 off and I am pretty sure I am being overcharged :(. All of their rates include taxes so it's not that. I'm clueless.

Comment: In the US, gasoline is always quoted as $\$x.xx9$ That is, prices always include $\frac 9{10}$ of a cent. It's been that way *forever* (it seems).